# HTML <div> horizontal alignment

Tags: css

I'm trying to align two divs horizontally. Having tried about 15 different approaches, I still don't manage to get it working.

> [image: This is how my divs are aligned now]

```
$html .= '<div class="fotoLinks">';
$html .= '  <img src="'.$image->getWebPath().'"/>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div class="tekst">';
$html .=    $this->text;
$html .= '</div>';
```

With corresponding CSS (div.alinea is a wrapper div):

```css
div.alinea
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.tekst
{
    float: left;
}

div.fotoLinks
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I hope to get some inspiration for a new approach.

Comment: Try the heredoc syntax for strings, or even better, put the html outside the php code, like this: `?>html goes here<?=$image->getWebPath()?>more html<?..`. It will make your life soo much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
display: inline-block;
```

Instead of `float: left;`

**EDIT:**

A method you can try, but is less supported, for your wrapper div, set:

```
display: table;
```

And for your inner divs:

```
display: table-cell;
```

Comment: Thanks, Sethi. Your edit seems to work pretty well. I still have to edit it to make it look a little better but the divs are aligned nicely now! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the width for your text div and image div, since as is it inherits the parent elements width of 100%.  There are a ton of others ways/answers, but this would have you tweak the least amount of code to get it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for `div.tekst`, put in `clear:both`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ftext {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ftext">
This is the left text.
</div>
<div class="ftext">
This follows to the left.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It floats the right text beside the left text.

Comment: The divs must be in a horizontal row. In this case: the text must be next to the picture

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. So the `float:left` should be sufficient. You must be somehow adding something else that complicates it. Can you post your full html / css for the page?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the 'tekst' div a left-margin. I didn't test this so I'm not sure that alone will fix it without adjusting something else.